# Characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, characters

Follow up question to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, how would I find  the characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$?

The Cayley table for this group:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
   (0,0,0) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    (0,0,1) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0)\\
    (0,1,0) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1)\\
    (0,1,1) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0)\\
    (1,0,0) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1)\\
    (1,0,1) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0)\\
    (1,1,0) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1)\\
    (1,1,1) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0)\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

***EDIT:***

The character table will have the form:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
   \chi_{(0,0,0)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(0,0,1)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,0)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,1)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,0)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,1)} & \pm 1 &\pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,0)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,1)} & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

But what is *a* possibility to make the table correct?

Comment: As this group is also abelian, the characters will take values $\pm 1$ however I don't know whether to use $1$ or $-1$ for any given element

Comment: so what are the possibilities for the character table?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is an abelian group, a character of $G$ is a homomorphism $\chi\colon G\to\mathbb{C}^*$ (multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers).

Suppose $G_1$ and $G_2$ are abelian groups and let $f_1\colon G_1\to G_1\oplus G_2$ and $f_2\colon G_2\to G_1\oplus G_2$ be the canonical embeddings.

Then a homomorphism $\chi\colon G_1\oplus G_2\to\mathbb{C}^*$ is completely determined by $\chi\circ f_1$ and $\chi\circ f_2$.

Similarly if you do the direct sum of more than two groups.

As the characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are known…

Comment: sorry I don't understand. the characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are known?

Comment: @Math Can you answer such questions without knowing the characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: sorry I misread your answer, I though it said characters of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are unknown